# How do I do an inner join in Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a table as follows :

id | loan_profile_id | from_state | to_state | date

there will be multiple entries for a particular loan_profile_id.

I want to use Hibernate to get the most recent entry before a particular time for a a set of  loan_profile_id's. This is how I would do it in SQL :

```
select lps.* from loan_profile_state_changes lps inner join 
(select max(id) as maxId from loan_profile_state_changes where date < '2012-09-13 00:00:00' and loan_profile_id in (15744,15745,15746,15747,15748,15750,15751) group by loan_profile_id)maxIds
on maxIds.maxId = lps.id order by lps.id desc;
```

How would i do this in hibernate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using Hibernate HQL

[The Hibernate Query Language: Subqueries](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-subqueries)

Comment: ... :) seems perfect duplicate of: [HQL: Is it possible to perform an INNER JOIN on a subquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624794/hql-is-it-possible-to-perform-an-inner-join-on-a-subquery)

Comment: is using a subquery efficient?

Comment: depends on your tables structure, indexing and dimension, yuo can run an `EXPLAIN` to see if your query work efficiently

Answer (score 0):

From Hibernate manual:

Assuming you have a "Cat" entity referencing another "Cat" entity as "mate",

```
from Cat as cat inner join cat.mate as mate
```

It could also be abbreviated as:

```
from Cat as cat join cat.mate as mate
```

Answer (score 0):

Using DetachedCriteria :

```
DetachedCriteria subQuery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(LoanProfileStateChanges.class);
subQuery.add(Restrictions.lt("date", new Date());
subQuery.add(Restrictions.in("id", Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
ProjectionList pl = Projections.projectionList();
pl.add(Projections.max("id")).add(Projections.groupProperty("loanProfileId"));
subQuery.setProjection(pl);

DetachedCriteria dc = DetachedCriteria.forClass(LoanProfileStateChanges.class);
dc.add(Subqueries.propertyIn("id", subQuery);
dc.addOrder(Order.desc("id"));
```

(note that it won't do a inner join, but is equivalent from an execution plan point of view)

Comment: meaning that when the database is queried, it will show as inner join is it?

Comment: Nop, it will show : select * from t1 where id in (your inner join)