# Trouble forming HQL query with inner join, result with multiple entities

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, postgresql, hql

I need to form an HQL query that returns multiple entity objects that looks something like this:

```
/*
 * Want to return both H and C in the same query...
 */
SELECT H, C
/*
 * ... such that H is the most recent entry...
 *
 * (Note that 'ON' keyword does not work with HQL)
 */
FROM HealthHistory H INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id, MAX(insertion_time) insertion_time
    FROM HealthHistory
    GROUP BY id
) IH ON H.id = IH.id AND IH.insertion_time = H.insertion_time
/*
 * ... while getting these other entities involved...
 */
LEFT JOIN NodeA A
LEFT JOIN NodeC C
LEFT JOIN NodeL L
/*
 * ... so we can add some more expressions here...
 */
WHERE A.someId = C.descendant.id -- A -> C
  AND A.something = someConstant
  AND C.someId = L.id -- C -> L
  AND C.something = someConstant
  AND L.something = someConstant
  AND H.someId = C.id -- H -> C
  AND H.something = someConstant
```

I keep receiving `org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: {(, A, ON, or INNER}`

I've been struggling for quite a while, even after looking over the many similar questions out there.  Any help out on this is appreciated...

Comment: You can not use 'ON' in hql. Use where in your query instant of ON.

Comment: [No subqueries in inner joins in HQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624794/hql-is-it-possible-to-perform-an-inner-join-on-a-subquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If somebody suggested an alternative to the above I would have marked it as the answer.  Since that's not the case, here is the work-around to get around the restriction around sub-queries and the lack of support for the 'ON' keyword:

```
SELECT H, C
FROM HealthHistory H,
     NodeA A,
     NodeC C,
     NodeL L
WHERE A.someId = C.descendant.id -- A -> C
  AND A.something = someConstant
  AND C.someId = L.id -- C -> L
  AND C.something = someConstant
  AND L.something = someConstant
  AND H.someId = C.id -- H -> C
  AND H.something = someConstant
  AND H.someId = C.descendant.id
  AND H.insertion_time IN (
                       SELECT MAX(insertion_time)
                       FROM HealthHistory H2
                       WHERE H2.someId = C.descendant.id
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need **ON** for HQL, you can find it [here for more info](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html).

Hibernate knows what is the join column without you telling it in the query as long as you map it in the entity.