# HQL select rows with max

Tags: select, hql

I got this table:

```
+---+----+----+----+
|ID |KEY1|KEY2|COL1|
+---+----+----+----+
|001|aaa1|bbb1|ccc1|
|101|aaa1|bbb1|ddd2|
|002|aaa2|bbb2|eee3|
|102|aaa2|bbb2|fff4|
|003|aaa3|bbb3|ggg5|
|103|aaa3|bbb3|hhh6|
+---+----+----+----+
```

The Result must contain the rows with the highest ID if the columns `key1` and `key2` are equals.

```
+---+----+----+----+
|ID |KEY1|KEY2|COL1|
+---+----+----+----+
|101|aaa1|bbb1|ddd2|
|102|aaa2|bbb2|fff4|
|103|aaa3|bbb3|hhh6|
+---+----+----+----+
```

Since in HQL I can't do a subquery like:

```
select * from (select....)
```

How can I perform this query?

`**SOLUTION**`

Actually the solution were a little bit more complex so i want share it since the `KEY1` and `KEY2` were on an other table which join on the first table with two keys.

```
+-----+-------+-------+-------+
|t1.ID|t2.KEY1|t2.KEY2|t1.COL1|
+-----+-------+-------+-------+
|  001|   aaa1|   bbb1|   ccc1|
|  101|   aaa1|   bbb1|   ddd2|
|  002|   aaa2|   bbb2|   eee3|
|  102|   aaa2|   bbb2|   fff4|
|  003|   aaa3|   bbb3|   ggg5|
|  103|   aaa3|   bbb3|   hhh6|
+-----+-------+-------+-------+
```

I used this `CORRECT` query:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t2.KEY1, t2.KEY2, t1.COL1
FROM yourTable1 t1, yourTable2 t2
WHERE 
t1.JoinCol1 = t2.JoinCol1 and t1.JoinCol2=t2.JoinCol2 and
t1.ID = (SELECT MAX(s1.ID) FROM yourTable1 s1, yourTable2 s2
         WHERE 
         s1.JoinCol1 = s2.JoinCol1 and s1.JoinCol2=s2.JoinCol2 and
         s2.KEY1 = t2.KEY1 AND s2.KEY2 = t2.KEY2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we were writing this query to be run directly on a regular database, such as MySQL or SQL Server, we might be tempted to join to a subquery.  However, from what I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624794/hql-is-it-possible-to-perform-an-inner-join-on-a-subquery), subqueries in HQL can only appear in the `SELECT` or `WHERE` clauses.  We can phrase your query as follows, using the `WHERE` clause to implement your logic.

The query will be:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.KEY1, t1.KEY2, t1.COL1
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE t1.ID = (SELECT MAX(t2.ID) FROM yourTable t2
               WHERE t2.KEY1 = t1.KEY1 AND t2.KEY2 = t1.KEY2)
```